# How to think about finding the Nash equilibrium of $f(x,y) = xy$

Tags: reference-request, solution-verification, intuition, game-theory

Let $x, y \in (-\infty, \infty)$

I know that  $f(x,y) = xy$ has a equilibrium at $(0,0)$, but I do not know how to logically arrive at this solution.

I know that a Nash equilibrium is when $\min_x\max_y xy = \max_y \min_x xy$

Start from the LHS, we have,
$$\min_x\max_y xy$$
The inner player goes first, which implies $y$ player will choose $\infty$, and $x$ will choose $-\infty$, yielding a value of $-\infty$.

For, $$\max_y \min_x xy$$

The inner player goes first and chooses $x = -\infty$, and outer player y will choose $-\infty$, yielding $\infty$.

It does not seem to me that the players can arrive at $(0,0)$. Because whoever goes second sets the value of the game.

What is missing?

Comment: Why is $(+\infty)\cdot(-\infty) = -\infty$?

Comment: Well if $x$ play any negative number than the payoff will be negative and it will be in the player $x$'s favor. Doesn't have to be $-\infty$ I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x > 0$, then $xy$ can be made as large and positive as we want, if we choose $y$ to be large and positive. So, for $x > 0$, $\sup_y xy = \infty$.

If $x < 0$, then $xy$ can still be made as large and positive as we want, this time choosing $y$ to be large and negative. So, for $x < 0$, $\sup_y xy = \infty$.

If $x = 0$, then no matter what $y$ chooses, the result of $xy$ is $0$. Thus, if $x = 0$, $\sup_y xy = 0$. Therefore,
$$\sup_y xy = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x = 0 \\ \infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Now, if we are taking the infimum (or indeed minimum) of this extended real function over all possible choices for $x$, we clearly need to choose $x = 0$, for a minimum of $0$.

Similar logic shows that
$$\inf_x xy = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } y = 0 \\ -\infty & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Thus, taking the maximum over $y$, we get $0$, which occurs when $x = 0$. Therefore, $(0, 0)$ is the Nash equilibrium.

Comment: thank you. It's so nuanced even for this silly example