# how to solve $\underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\min} xy$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Assume $x(t),y(t)$ map to $\mathbb R$. I want to solve
$$\underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\min} xy$$

The solution is supposedly
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= y\\
\dot{y} &= -x\\
\end{align*}

My professor did not provide more explaination for how to derive this.

I tried a few things. I first defined $f(x,y) = xy$. Then I did
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}  + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}&  = 0\\
&= y\dot{x}  + x\dot{y}&= 0\\
\end{align*}
I also tried
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= y \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= x\\
\end{align*}

Neither of these ended up helping me see his approach. My final attempt was

$$\underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\min} xy \Rightarrow  \underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\max} -xy$$

But I realized this isn't right either because it's not the same.

Can anyone give me a pointer how they got this solution? Even knowing what to google would help. I tried a few things but found nothing.

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean by “solve” that value.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? It wouldn't surprise me if the problem is constructed poorly. My professor is notorious for bad notation and many typos, so i'm not even convinced the problem is well-posed mathematically.

Comment: He proposed this set up as a simplified version of a GAN, the type of deep neural network used for deep fakes.

Comment: Has your issue something to do with Lyapunov functions https://www.ndsu.edu/pubweb/~novozhil/Teaching/480%20Data/13.pdf ?

Comment: ... or with Nash equilibrium https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4053379 ? It"s hard to say...

Comment: @JeanMarie I feel like the idea behind this problem is much more like the Lyapunov example. But I'm not confident if that's what my professor indended

Comment: @Stan Shunpike :$\quad \underset{x}{\max} \underset{y}{\min} xy\quad$ is not an equation. There is no $=$ in it. Thus solving it is non-sens.